# Why Maven assemble plugin needs to download dependencies pom file every run

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am working on Jenkins to make my project to be packaged automatically. But it concerns me that Maven assemble plugin downloads dependencies pom files every time and it is very time-consuming for me. Who can help me out, thanks in advance.

[image: maven running output]

Comment: Do not post links of pictures. Better post text content into post...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I just wanna copy output of maven,
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:3.0.0:single (make-assembly) @ AutoHub ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.10/jersey-client-1.10.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.10/jersey-core-1.10.pom